# Different behaviours with getline and cin together with condition

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, cin, getline

I have a continuous `while` loop, inside which I get user input indefinitely until the user passes no input, i.e, presses enter, or an EOF is encountered (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

The first attempt, I use `getline` function.

```
while (true)
    {   
        if (not (std::getline(std::cin, sm)) or sm.empty())
            break;
    }
```

It works fine, exits the loop on no input or EOF.

On the second attempt I use standard `cin`:

```
while (true)
{   
    if (not (std::cin >> sm) or sm.empty())
        break;
}
```

In this case, it does no longer work as intended. It does not exit the loop when user presses enter, only on entering EOF it exits.

What is the difference? What am I missing here?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "it does not longer work as intended"?

Comment: I meant it does not exit the loop when the use presses enter. It only exits on EOF. Unlike the previous case where it was exiting on both pressing enter and EOF. I have edited my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `std::cin >> sm` skips leading whitespace (including blank lines). `getline` does not. `std::cin >> sm` reads whitespace-delimited tokens, and doesn't treat end-of-line characters differently from, say, space characters. It'll never produce an empty string unless end-of-file or another failure is encountered.

Comment: If they had identical behaviour we wouldn't need both of them.